# Hibernate many-to-one self-join association cascade update doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, cascade

I have this self-join entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PackageTemplate")
public class PackageTemplate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long idPackageTemplate;

    private Byte status;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to PackageTemplate
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "packageTemplate")
    private PackageTemplate packageTemplate;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to PackageTemplate
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "packageTemplate", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "PackageTemplate", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "packageTemplate", nullable = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idPackageTemplate", nullable = false) })
    private List<PackageTemplate> packageTemplateList;

     public PackageTemplate() {
    }

    public Long getIdPackageTemplate() {
        return this.idPackageTemplate;
    }

    public Byte getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Byte status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public PackageTemplate getPackageTemplate() {
        return this.packageTemplate;
    }

    public void setPackageTemplate(PackageTemplate packageTemplate) {
        this.packageTemplate = packageTemplate;
    }

    public List<PackageTemplate> getPackageTemplateList() {
        return this.packageTemplateList;
    }

    public void setPackageTemplateList(List<PackageTemplate> packageTemplateList) {
        this.packageTemplateList = packageTemplateList;
    }
}
```

When I update a packageTemplate setting PackageTemplateList, it doesn´t work. The related items keep the relationship with father.

No errors showed, just seems that cascade does nothing.

Any idea?

---

Solved, 
[JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) was right. The problem was the "mappedBy in packageTemplateList".

The code should be something like this:

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to PackageTemplate
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "packageTemplate")
private PackageTemplate packageTemplate;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to PackageTemplate
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "packageTemplate")
private List<PackageTemplate> packageTemplateList;
```

This code is working now.

Comment: Show us your code (the code which creates and adds package templates), and fix your mapping. `mappedBy` means: The mapping of this association is on the other side of the association. So you shouldn't have a JoinTable annotation on packageTemplateList. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896025/understanding-annotations-and-jpahibernate/19896470#19896470

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing setting a back reference on the children to their parent.

You can achieve this by the following code in the setPackageTemplateList method.

```
public void setPackageTemplateList(List<PackageTemplate> packageTemplateList) {

    for(PackageTemplate template : PackageTemplateList) {
        template.setPackageTemplate(this);
    }
    this.packageTemplateList = packageTemplateList;
}
```