# Persist JPA collection oneToMany doesnt work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've  this selfRelationship annotation

```
public class Estoria implements Serializable {

 @EmbeddedId 
 protected EstoriaPK estoriaPK; 

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "id_estoria", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = true)
          ,@JoinColumn(name = "id_projeto" , referencedColumnName = "id_projeto" ,     insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private Estoria subtask;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subtask",cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
private Collection<Estoria> subtasks; 

}
```

and I try to persist this collection::

```
public void persistSubtasks(int idEstoria, Collection<Estoria> subtasks) {
    Estoria rootEstoria = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Estoria.findById", Estoria.class)
                    .setParameter("id", idEstoria)
                    .getSingleResult();

        rootEstoria.setSubtasks(subtasks);
}
```

But the database persistence didnt persist root reference id:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------     -------------------------------------------------------------------+------   ------+--------+--------------+
| id | id_projeto | id_estoria | nome                     | descricao                                                                      | estimativa | status | data_criacao |
+----+------------+------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |          7 |       NULL | Check all old activities | No one know if every feature was checked before builded                      |       NULL |      0 | 2015-01-02   |
|  2 |          7 |       "supost to be 1" | Register all users       | Everyone needs to be registered and identified by profile                    |       NULL |      0 | 2015-01-02   |
```

Could anyone give me some adivice?

Good news this post > [Understanding annotations and JPA(hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896025/understanding-annotations-and-jpahibernate/19896470#19896470) solved my problem but i dont really though about that I need reference both root >> leaf / leaf >> root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set parrent id in Child Ids. Set rootEstoria id in subtasks collection.

```
public void persistSubtasks(int idEstoria, Collection<Estoria> subtasks) {
    Estoria rootEstoria = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Estoria.findById", Estoria.class)
                .setParameter("id", idEstoria)
                .getSingleResult();
    for(Estoria subtask:subtasks){
        subtask.setSubtask(rootEstoria);
    }
    rootEstoria.setSubtasks(subtasks);
}
```

Comment: @smartphonne .Thats good news .  If it works then you can  accept answer and vote up . So that others can find the answer is useful

Comment: Nice! i forgot ; did it now